# smarty - replace all after comma

Tags: php, smarty

I am trying to replace all after comma from a smarty variable.

The output of $price is 50,23

But my code does not work:

```
{$price|preg_replace('/^([^,]*).*$/', '$1', $price)}
```

Does someone know how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.regex.replace.tpl) it should be

```
{$price|regex_replace:'/^([^,]*).*$/':'$1'}
```